# How to find a column field which is not primary key in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have a situation like this if the user enters a particular number which is already present in the DB I should throw exception.

I tried to use em.find method in JPA but in em.find method we need to pass entity class and primary key but here the column I want to find is not primary key.

Ex:em.find("Article.class",articleno); where articleno is not primary key

And for this Article.class I have a composite primary key(ArticlePk.class)  where id and origin are primary keys.

how to find the article no using composite primary key.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Do you need to use em.Find only? meaning you can also write a JQL in this case and pass articleNo as input parameter.

Comment: Yes I have a code writen by other developer so i need to use that code is there anyway to do that

Comment: you need to pass in composite primary key in em.find() correct?

Comment: but how can you give an example

Comment: If something is a composite PK then how is it "not primary key"?! contradiction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get article object based on composite Primary key, please see below

```
ArticlePk articlePk = new ArticlePk();

articlePk .setId(1);
articlePk .setOrigin("");

Article article = em.find(Article .class, articlePk);
```

Please make sure that ArticlePk  implements Serializable

**If you strictly want to query by articleNo then you can for JQL approach, you can write query as shown below**:

```
List results = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article a where a.articleNo = :articleNo")
                        .setParameter("articleNo", "").getResultList();
```

In this case if `List` is empty, that means `article` for that `articleNo` is not found in `DB`

Comment: But how can we check whether the articleno is existing we are only passing id and origin ..?


I need to pass the article no as well as right to check whether it is there in db..how can we pass artpk,artorigin,articlee no into em.find

Comment: As I said before, then in that case you have to either go for JQL or JPQL or Criteria or even native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your situation well. If you are using @EmbeddedId here, then you may get it easily.

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ArticlePk key;

    @Column(name = "Article_No")
    private String articleNo;

    /** Your getters and setters **/
}

@Embeddable
public class ArticlePK implements Seriza {

    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Origin", nullable = false)
    private String origin;

    /** getters and setters **/
}
```

In your DAO implementation;

```
ArticlePK artPK = new ArticlePK();

artPK.setId(12334);
artPK.setOrigin("ABC123");

Article article = em.find(Article.class, artPK);
System.out.printl("Article no: " + article.getArticleNo());
```

Comment: But how can we check whether the articleno is existing we are only passing id and origin ..?

I need to pass the article no as well as right to check whether it is there in db..how can we pass artpk,artorigin,articlee no into em.find

Comment: once you got the article instance you may check if this instance(record) has any articleNo or not. Perhaps you might define article no as Not Null and be sure it is always field?